# Convert DATETIME to 8 digit INT in format YYYYMMDD SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, int

Need to join two tables. One table has a 'datekey' column  that is an int in the format YYYYMMDD from the dimdate table, and the other table has a 'CreatedOn' column that is a datetime. I am casting the datetime to a date initially because that is the only way the group by seems to work correctly. I keep getting the error "Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int" because of the "on d.datekey = BBB.datekey" line.. any suggestions on an easy workaround?

```
select 
    distinct CONVERT (date,convert(char(8),d.datekey )) as Date
    , isnull(BBB.reccount,0) DimAccount
from dimdate d
left outer join(
    Select 
        cast(createdon as date) datekey
        , count(*) RecCount
    from DimAccount 
    group by cast(createdon as date)
)BBB on d.datekey = BBB.datekey
where d.datekey like '2017%'
group by d.datekey
,BBB.RecCount
having MAX(DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date, CAST(d.Datekey  AS CHAR(8)), 101), GETDATE())) > -1
order by date desc
```

Comment: did u try converting to varchar & then to int ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime google is your friend (and docs too)

Comment: @AlekhyaVemavarapu that still returns 0 for all dates in the query, I'm not sure why

Comment: @DanBracuk sql server, in visual studio if that is what you mean

Comment: What are the other fields in the dimDate table?

Comment: @DanBracuk there are many.. some include year (datetime,null), year_name (nvarchar(50),null), week, day of month, day of week, etc. any date column you could think of

Comment: you are trying to match int with datetime column on d.datekey = BBB.datekey

Comment: you can use  select convert(int,convert(varchar(10), getdate(),112))

Comment: @KashifQureshi yes  I know I wrote that in the description

Comment: @KannanKandasamy that only returns the current date, I am trying to gather every day this year

Comment: In that case you an use YEAR()

Comment: it will be easier if you can please provide some sample data from both table.

Answer (score 2):

something like this should get you started

```
from dimDate dd join dimAccount da 
on cast(da.createdOn as date) = cast(cast(dd.dateKey as char(8)) as date)

where dd.year = 2017  -- or you can filter on da.createdOn >= '20170101'
```

In fact, if your dimDate table has an actual date column you wouldn't have to cast the dateKey at all.